# BuildError when using redirect between py files in Flask

Tags: python, flask

I have a main landing page that I would like to use for linking to separate modules in Flask. I can't seem to connect them using url_for or any other method. It will load main.html with the link to App 1, but it breaks right there.

I'm getting **"werkzeug.routing.BuildError: Could not build url for endpoint 'app1'. Did you mean 'load_myapp' instead?"**

It feels like I'm just missing maybe one thing, but I can't seem to figure out what.

Example of my file structure according to the Flask documentation:

```
my_app
 setup.py
-my_app
  __init__.py
  app1.py
```

Setup.py:

```
from setuptools import setup

setup(
    name='my_app',
    packages=['my_app'],
    include_package_data=True,
    install_requires=[
        'flask',
    ],
)
```

```
__init__.py:


from flask import Flask, render_template, url_for, redirect

app = Flask(__name__)

import my_app.app1

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('main.html')

@app.route('/load_myapp')
def load_myapp():
    return redirect(url_for('app1'))
```

app1.py

```
from flask import Flask, render_template
from my_app import app


@app.route('/app1')
def app1():
        return render_template("app1.html")
```

Main.html:

```
<body>

    <a href="{{ url_for('load_myapp') }}">App 1</a>

</body>
```

Thanks ahead of time for any help.

Comment: What does "it breaks right there" mean? What link is generated?

Comment: I'm getting "werkzeug.routing.BuildError: Could not build url for endpoint 'app1'. Did you mean '/load_mayapp' instead?"